# Download file using stream + jquery + asp.net handlers

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, stream

Im trying to download a file using a stream via my handler and jquery, i have a handler that return a Stream

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context){

    string name = "MyFile.xlsx"        

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    context.Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name ); 
    Stream stream = GetFileStream("id001");

    context.Response.Write (stream);
}
```

And a page that process this handler, but i cant map the response

```
    function downloadFile(e) {
        var baseUrl = "./handlers/DownloadReport.ashx?";
        e.preventDefault();            
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        var key = "key=" + dataItem.Link;
        var name = "&name=" + dataItem.ReportName;
        $.get(baseUrl + key + name, function (result) {
            // Check for errors 

        });
    }
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that jQuery either doesn't get the stream EOF, or that the connection is closed when the stream is finished and therefore the javascript can't handle it.

You could try to get the stream with the jQuery stream plugin, maybe that helps:
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-stream/wiki/API